# How can I resolve VBA FORMAT function issue?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, format

I am using the FORMAT function is Excel 2103 VBA, but I'm not getting the expected results.

My line of code is:

```
strMonthNo = Format(Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Date)), "mm")
```

Where `Date` is 29/11/2016, I would expect `strMonthNo = 10`, but it isn't. It's 01!

Without FORMAT, the value is correct.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output of `Month` is a number, not a date.

`Format(x,"mm")` expect x to be a date, so it handles it being 10th of January 1900, that's why the result is `1`.

Just use
`Format(Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Date)), "00")`

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the same thing twice.

`DateAdd` is giving you the date you want to work with - The date one month ago today. The `Month` function is then extracting the month from that date - currently 10.

The `FORMAT` function is then taking *that month* - 10 - and interpreting it as a full date, ie January 10th 1900. *This* is what you're formatting to show only the month.

You need to remove either `MONTH` or `FORMAT`. Either of these should work:

```
strMonthNo = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date))

strMonthNo = Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Date))
```